# Initial-letter property of ::first-letter pseudo element not working

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-size: 200px;
  initial-letter: 3;
  -webkit-first-letter: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis
      deserunt vero ipsam dolores aut excepturi cumque non perferendis tempore
      ea? Enim saepe corrupti voluptates? Neque non nostrum, maiores facere nam
      labore dignissimos quis est ea enim deleniti molestias consectetur velit
      amet ad repellendus explicabo assumenda laudantium magnam eum numquam
      praesentium voluptates odit iure. Explicabo, ad? Blanditiis quaerat
      accusamus, pariatur animi sit, illum laborum placeat earum expedita ad
      maiores est! Nisi odit distinctio, hic, nihil iure eum maxime mollitia
      nostrum aperiam ipsa minus cumque harum. Cupiditate, sunt nihil. Fugit,
      sed odit, iusto nisi culpa facilis quis ratione eum pariatur ex maiores!
      Est atque amet, at tempore error earum ab aspernatur placeat vel quos
      animi quas minima, praesentium voluptatum nemo autem quasi nam maxime
      totam magnam ad ullam. Commodi corrupti soluta repudiandae totam porro
      nihil dolorum quaerat reprehenderit assumenda repellat officia aliquid
      similique autem tempore, ducimus non. Obcaecati harum doloremque natus
      totam expedita, delectus quis, nisi dignissimos saepe, maiores debitis
      cupiditate ipsam enim! Optio eligendi possimus ea fugit eum odit
      accusantium maxime, distinctio maiores dolorum atque, vero quia culpa
      provident, voluptas earum voluptatum nam impedit ex nesciunt deserunt?
      Laboriosam in dolores blanditiis eveniet necessitatibus voluptate delectus
      cum, error modi officia, itaque consequuntur non sit quis, quibusdam
      veritatis rerum corrupti! Deserunt, expedita nesciunt laudantium quas,
      iusto natus vitae, eveniet voluptatem voluptas mollitia quam dicta
      quisquam. Exercitationem eveniet, rem alias obcaecati officiis beatae et
      laudantium perspiciatis similique nesciunt, error magni nemo?
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why the `initial-letter: 3;` is not working? What am I missing? I am using Google Chrome.

Many thanks

Comment: Per MDN [`initial-letter` is only supported in Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial-letter#Browser_compatibility).  So I would guess that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time  @AlexanderNied . Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, exactly?  Just give the large red text treatment to the third letter in the copy?  Do you have the access/ability to change the markup as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question.

Unfortunately, at this point (May 2020), the CSS property `initial-letter` is not yet supported by any browser.

See:

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-letter

---

Once it *is* supported, note that `initial-letter` may take a second (optional) value:

```
initial-letter: 3 2;
```

where:

- the first value indicates how many lines the `initial-letter` occupies; and
- the second value indicates the number of lines to which the `initial-letter` is sunk.

If the second value is omitted, it is assumed to be identical to the first value.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial-letter

---

**Example (not working, because not yet supported):**

```css
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
  -webkit-initial-letter: 3 2;
  initial-letter: 3 2;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis deserunt vero ipsam dolores aut excepturi cumque non perferendis tempore ea? Enim saepe corrupti voluptates? Neque non nostrum, maiores facere nam labore dignissimos quis est ea enim deleniti molestias consectetur velit amet ad repellendus explicabo assumenda laudantium magnam eum numquam praesentium voluptates odit iure. Explicabo, ad? Blanditiis quaerat accusamus, pariatur animi sit, illum laborum placeat earum expedita ad maiores est! Nisi odit distinctio, hic, nihil iure eum maxime mollitia nostrum aperiam ipsa minus cumque harum. Cupiditate, sunt nihil. Fugit, sed odit, iusto nisi culpa facilis quis ratione eum pariatur ex maiores! Est atque amet, at tempore error earum ab aspernatur placeat vel quos animi quas minima, praesentium voluptatum nemo autem quasi nam maxime totam magnam ad ullam. Commodi corrupti soluta repudiandae totam porro nihil dolorum quaerat reprehenderit assumenda repellat officia aliquid similique autem tempore, ducimus non.</p>
```